# Plugins to Blackberry media player

Tags: blackberry, media-player

Does Blackberry media player (the built-in one) allow any 3rd party plugins? I am thinking to add a forward/backward 5 seconds function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no plugin support for the native media player.  However there are lots of articles in the RIM documentation that explain how to create your own media player application, which might be an option if you're up for it.  Take a look at a recent [blog post](http://devblog.blackberry.com/2010/05/streaming-player-api/) for more information and some sample code.